# white and brown mushrooms. same species but...?

Tags: mycology

On [Cooking SE](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/61617/is-it-possible-to-ripen-mushrooms-after-its-picked) and [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agaricus_bisporus) we wonder if someone can claify:

Are white vs brown immature fruiting bodies of *Agaricus bisporus* different stages of development like many kinds of fruit change color as they ripen? Or are they different cultivars or are they due to different environmental conditions when forming?

Bonus: what isnthe brown pigmentation? Is the difference in taste due to that or meerly correlated with it but due to some other difference?